# How to start liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2 server start windows service in server2008 r2

Tags: java, tomcat, liferay, portal

I need to start the `Liferay portal tomcat server` start with windows service in `windows server 2008 R2`,

http://javatheking.wordpress.com/2012/04/17/installing-liferay-tomcat-bundle-as-a-windows-service/

I followed these link in windows 7 its worked. but I need to run server 2008 R2. I got an error which is given below.

> Error:   The Liferay Portal 6.1 CE service on Local Computer started
>   and then stopped. Some services stop automatically if they are not in
>   use by other services or programs.

If any one knows about these issues, please help

Thanks,

Vijay

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution:

1)      Click Run Command from start button

2)      Enter `Services.msc` then click OK,you will get all the services in your computer.

3)      Select your service and right click on the service and select Properties

4)      Goto Logon Properties and select  `Local System Account` then click OK

Answer (score 0):

Hi I was facing same issue.

I have dig up and found that in setting, under shutdown tab, time was set to 0. so i remove that and try again and service start fine!!